# Flutter MissingPluginException when I use FlutterFragmentActivity

Tags: flutter, dart, localauthentication

After upgrading to 1.17.3 and (1.17.3) I can't use *local_auth* biometric plugin anymore. Plugin requires `FlutterFragmentActivity`, but once I change `public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity` to `public class MainActivity extends FlutterFragmentActivity` app would compile and run but I'd start getting `MissingPluginException` error for every other plugin.

Comment: Found a similar post that was helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62210423/flutter-local-auth-doesnt-work-on-android-28

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution, it seems it has not been added to the *local_auth* documentation. Make sure to add the configureFlutterEngine override method as below after changing from FlutterActivity to FlutterFragmentActivity in the MainActivity Class

```
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine;
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant;
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterFragmentActivity;

public class MainActivity extends FlutterFragmentActivity {
    @Override
    public void configureFlutterEngine(FlutterEngine flutterEngine) {
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Just a little note: Be sure to import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterFragmentActivity  Instead of  io.flutter.app.FlutterFragmentActivity